# execute php via mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, stored-procedures, programming-languages

Is it possible to execute a php file using mysql stored procedure or event scheduler?

Comment: postgresql has such a feature (though not for php, but for perl, python, tcl), see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/xplang.html

Comment: It's probably not possible, and for good reason. Making calls to external pages or scripts would entail a lot of settings, parameters and eventualities to take care of. Use cron jobs.

Comment: Will you please tell us what you are up to?

Comment: @Pekka: It doesn't necessarily have to be a new process (if that's what you meant). It could be a script handler that resides within the database server's process, much like mod_php resides within the httpd process. And I was wrong about postgresql not having a php handler. It's not in the core but yet it exists: see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/external-pl.html

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040241/is-there-any-way-i-can-execute-a-php-script-from-mysql

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware this is impossible. And I can't really imagine a scenario where you'd want to do this. Can't you schedule a task with cronjob/task scheduler that executes a PHP file in the background?

Comment: looks like it is now possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.
What are your intentions to use it for?

Comment: I want to use mysql to export the data to a csv file and email that csv file to the client. The email part i was thinking of coding it in php.

Comment: why don't you grab the datafrom the db (with php), create the cvs file and mail it (with php)?

Comment: looks like it is now possible.

Answer (score 0):

Such a feature has not been implemented in the MYSQL server (yet?), but you might be interested in

- http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/ProjectPage_External_Language_Stored_Procedures
- http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/index.php