# Is there any way I can execute a PHP script from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to invoke and execute a PHP script from a MySQL procedure. Is this possible?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
    BEGIN
         Call my php script here
    END//
```

**[EDIT]**
I am in fact trying to raise an event when a condition is met — for instance when my table field  value matches the current time. Then, I want to capture the event and send an email.

Comment: No You cant!!  Share your exact problem we try to find alternative solutions.

Comment: No you can't thou you could retrieve php script from the database and call eval function, but whatever you are doinbg it would be plain wrong

Comment: Try to look at `do_system()` in http://www.databasesecurity.com/mysql/HackproofingMySQL.pdf

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943205/execute-php-via-mysql?rq=1

Comment: A cron script is probably better than using a database trigger for this

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's possible, See the MySQL FAQ for an explanation of how

[Can triggers call an external application through a UDF?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-10)

But it's likely to be bad design on your part if you have to resort to this

Answer (score 12):

```
DELIMITER @@

CREATE TRIGGER Test_Trigger
AFTER INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE result int(10);
SET cmd=CONCAT('/usr/bin/php ', '/home/test/beta/demo.php');
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);

END;
@@
DELIMITER ;
```

[**source**](http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.pt/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html)

Comment: Dont have time to test.. Does it really work? Did you test? Looks great!

Answer (score 3):

For solve your problem you can create table for tasks. 
From stored procedure you can put to this table any string for task.
On server you can run PHP script by crontab. Script will check this table and make some operation.