# Call php function from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, zend-framework

I am using zend php framework. Is this is possible to call zend php controller from stored procedure?

If yes, could you explain that with example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way I can execute a PHP script from MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040241/is-there-any-way-i-can-execute-a-php-script-from-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is directly not supported. The only one chance you have is to write your own [User Defined Function - UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-functions.html) where you submit a request via the OS to the PHP page and return the result.

But, this is not really that trivial.

Comment: I need to execute a zend controller action at particular time. I use crontab. But in my scenario, call particular action time is saved in database. Is their is any other way?

Comment: @Deepak I don't have enough information to understand your problem 100% but why don't you execute a PHP script and this calls the stored procedure with the result - if it is possible.

Comment: I need to send a mail that list of employees comes late. Work start time will be specified on table column. lateEmployeeList = workstarttime + 10 min(grace time). so that i need to call a action to get employee whom are comes late. Is their is any way?

Comment: @Deepak Why stored procedures? As you wrote, you run a cron job running each 15 minutes [for example]. This cron job calls a PHP script which performs the check and sends an email if somebody is too late.

Comment: I try crontab. But mail is not sending. Can you chack this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087059/schedule-action-call-in-zend-framework-php-using-crontab